# What triggers an System.InvalidCastException in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an issue on my ASP.NET 4.0 application. The error appears when I call one of my subroutines in the App_Code folder. I call the subroutine when a button is clicked on the page.

```
Protected Sub imgBtnEmailReg_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles imgBtnEmailReg.Click
    Dim functions As New Functions
    Dim pidm As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Session("BannerPidm").ToString)
    functions.sendStudentAccomLetter(pidm)
End Sub
```

After the button click the id number is sent to the App_Code/Functions.vb where my subroutine is:

```
Public Sub sendStudentAccomLetter(ByVal stuPidm As Integer)
...
End Sub
```

The error I get when calling the above function is:

"System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at Functions.sendStudentAccomLetter(Int32 stuPidm) in D:\www-sec-docs\DisabilityServices\App_Code\Functions.vb:line 259"

Line 259 is the sub signature. I'm not even sure if there is a cast occurring here. Can someone please explain what might be causing this. Thank you.

Comment: What value is Session("BannerPidm") returning ?

Comment: The value for Session("BannerPidm") = "######" where # is a unique identifier for students of the university such as "123456". (It isn't literally # but the number for the student)

Comment: Let me just add that my code in the sub "sendStudentAccomLetter(ByVal stuPidm As Integer)" executes completely and correctly (It converts the message to a pdf and emails to the student). So my fix may just be to suppress the error and press on, yet I know this is poor practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Session("BannerPidm") value may be a different type - the method declaration is not the cause of the cast error. Try implementing some kind of check on the Session("BannerPidm") value such as:

```
If IsNumeric(Session("BannerPidm")) Then
   'Proceed
```

Comment: The error was not caused originally by the sub declaration as you suggested. Rather, external references within my sub may have caused the stacktrace to point to the wrong line. The problem was indeed an incorrect cast within the sub (at the very bottom) thank you for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

This link shows a few examples where you would get  and error when trying to convert: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/514682-difference-between-cint-convert-toint32

Try using `CInt()` instead and see if you still have problems. If you do, then you may want to start checking what the session variable is and see if there is a better, more standardized way you can store it.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I tried using CInt as suggested which did not change the outcome. I got similar results with Integer.parse().

Comment: Then I would check what your `Session("BannerPidm")` is set to. If it's not able to convert it, then the data being stored in it is wrong. Check to see where that session object gets set, and perhaps write its value to a log so you can review what it's trying to convert.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely the conversion to Int32.  Set a breakpoint at that line, and see what value `Session("BannerPidm")` 
is returning.  There is definitely a cast occurring, because you are retrieving from Session, casting it to string (`.ToString()`), then converting that to Int32.

Comment: The Integer pidm is set to a value: 285### (# represent integers) when the sub sendStudentAccom is called. This pidm is correct with what is stored in the Session("BannerPidm").